# How can I disable or hide the scrollbar within an Ionic 2 <ion-content>

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have an Angular 2 app wrapped in Ionic 2. I'm using `<ion-tabs>`, and within each tab is an `<ion-content>`. The content in this area needs to be scrollable, but Ionic 2 adds a scrollbar that I don't want displayed. It appears that, when compiled, an `<ion-content>` has a `<scroll-content>` injected into it. I don't want this behavior.

I have tried many of the solutions that *used to* work in Ionic 1, but they do not work in Ionic 2:

- Setting `scroll="false"` on the `<ion-content>`
- Setting `scrollbar-y="false"` on the `<ion-content>`
- Setting `overflow-scroll="false"` on the `<ion-content>`
- Setting the following in css:

  `.scroll-bar-indicator
  {
      display: none;
  }`

etc...

Setting the following actually does work to remove the scrollbar, but I'd rather not hijack the browser behavior, and also it removes scrollbars from content internal to the `<ion-content>` tag, which I don't want.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yea, same here... as far as i know it seems that the ionic team didn't added this options for now, so i think the only way is hijacking the browser like you did, but add it to a class that you use only in a specific <ion-content> that you want to hide the scrollbar. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for your hijacking solution, it works, and I don't see a reason to keep a scrollbar in my app, so I prefer to remove it permanently.

Comment: Did you get solution for this @vrjr?

Comment: @Aish123 I haven't looked into it since around the time I posted this question, but eventually I came to the conclusion that what I wanted to do was not currently possible with Ionic 2. The situation with Ionic 2 may have changed then since it was under rapid development in alpha status at the time.

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
} worked for me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

They have a class for that and should be able to use:

```
 import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

 constructor(private app: App) {
   app.setScrollDisabled(true);
};
```

See forum discussion [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7644/#issuecomment-238937901). But it seems to have stopped working after **2.0.0-rc.1** I believe thats related to [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-behavior-of-icons-in-buttons) in their **CHANGELOG** when they changed a lot of attributes to classes (i.e. `scroll-content` to `.scroll-content`) and the `app.setScrollDisabled(true);` hasn't been updated to reflect some of those changes.

If your using **2.0.0-rc.2** or **2.0.0-rc.3** I don't believe `<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">` or `<ion-content  ion-fixed>` will work either so from now create your own class.

So if you're on **2.0.0-rc.2** or **2.0.0-rc.3** you should be able to do so by adding this to your `.scss`

```
.no-scroll .scroll-content{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

and add this class to your `ion-content` like this

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
..
</ion-content>
```

So now just keep an eye out for this being fixed on versions after **2.0.0-rc.3**.

---

**UPDATE (2.0.0-rc.6):** It looks like they made the `App` modules `setDisableScroll` function private (as seen [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/7b2a6d523ebdf7898ffed90d9c2574a15e8d09f0))

Also here's a full list of the available function for the `App` module by version:

- [2.0.0-rc.1](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-rc.1/api/components/app/App/#setScrollDisabled) (has **setScrollDisabled**)
- [2.0.0-rc.2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-rc.2/api/components/app/App/#setScrollDisabled) (has **setScrollDisabled**)
- [2.0.0-rc.3](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-rc.3/api/components/app/App/#setScrollDisabled) (has **setScrollDisabled**)
- [2.0.0-rc.4](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/app/App/) (no **setScrollDisabled**, and no alternative)
- [2.0.0-rc.5](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/app/App/) (still no **setScrollDisabled** or alternative)
- [2.0.0-rc.6](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/app/App/) (no **setScrollDisabled**, and no alternative but they did a a lot more view tirgger functions like `viewWillUnload`)

So unless they bring it back keep using the following:

.no-scroll .scroll-content{
         overflow: hidden;
    }

Also I'm a sucker for them internet points so preeez upvote if you found this helpful.

Comment: Yes your right, running 2.0.0-rc.3 adding the custom class did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohsen I updated my answer. They removed the `setScrollDisabled` altogether looks like.

Comment: This disabled the scrolling and the scrollbar together

Comment: Thanks for updating this information, it should really be incorporated into ionic2 changelog.  Your CSS is working for me.  I hope to get notified by SO if this changes again and you update.

Comment: In ionic 2 it's app._setDisableScroll(true);

Answer (score 19):

In ionic2 I saw overflow-y is set to scroll by default so in your src/app/app.scss file try this:

```
.scroll-content {
   overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

This will hide scroll bar from every view and also enable scrolling when it has content.

Comment: I added the following CSS code and it disabled the scroll on an ion-content directive:

    .scroll-content {
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
    }

Answer (score 7):

You can override the scroll-content style in your `.scss` file.

```
// scroll-content is a class
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

or better still you can set `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work because it removes the ability to scroll. I only want to remove the scroll _bar_, not the scroll _behavior_.

Comment: set only overflow-y as auto ,this just hides but doesn'y disable functionality, tried it, works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to **hide the scroll-bar**, and not want to disable the scrolling itself, then use `no-bounce` attr:

```
<ion-content no-bounce></ion-content>
```

thanks to [larssn for his comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7644#issuecomment-280039575)

But if **you don't want the scroll** you may also don't need the ion-content itself, in my status for example I want to use the ion-grid directly.

```
<!-- my-page.ts >
<ion-header>.......</ion-header>
<ion-grid class="has-header fixed-content">

</ion-grid>
```

and I added some scss for the has-header class:

```
ion-app {
    &.md {
        .has-header {
            margin-top: $toolbar-md-height;
        }
    }
    &.wp {
        .has-header {
            margin-top: $toolbar-wp-height;
        }
    }
    &.ios {
        .has-header {
            margin-top: $toolbar-ios-height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  The `ion-content` description is all about support for scrolling.  "The Content component provides an easy to use content area with some useful methods to control the scrollable area. There should only be one content in a single view component. If additional scrollable elements are need, use ionScroll."  *So if you don't want scrolling using ion-grid instead*.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ionic 2 rc 0

My solution is to use an ion-fixed attribute on a div I called envelope.

(in rc 0, you can't add ion-fixed to ion-content)

```
<ion-content>
  <div id='envelope' ion-fixed>
  </div>
</ionic-content>

#envelope{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in config.xml works for me.

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic2 has added setScrollDisabled with underscore prefix.
So if you would like to access just make use of injectable variable app and try to set the this.app._setScrollDisabled(true).I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css into your styles,

I fetched this class from inspect element which contains scrollbar and items

```
ion-scroll.scroll-y .scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
```

worked for me

Comment: Thank You, Work for me.
But Mozilla Firefox not proper working.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work perfectly in my Ionic5/Angular11 app while retaining scroll events and hiding the scrollbar with the code below:

```
ion-content {
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  --padding-end: 40px !important;
}

ion-content::part(scroll) {
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

use overflow-scroll="false" in ion-content