# Ionic 2 <ion-content> disable scroll

Tags: scroll, ionic2

I've tried several methods to disable scroll, including using CSS `position: fixed`, attribute `overflow-scroll="false"` and etc, but all methods failed.

When I swipe down, the buttons will go up and while I swipe up the buttons will go down, like bouncing effect.

May I know any solutions to this issue? Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 41):

Tested with ionic 3 (should work on ionic 2):

```
<ion-content no-bounce></ion-content>
```

Comment: For anybody with an up to date version of Ionic – this is the best answer for the time being. See: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7644

Comment: After removing any element that had a bigger height than the content, this worked for me aswell

Comment: Max from Ionic here, it's clear we need to make this way easier. We're passing around this issue internally to make sure we fix this going forward!

Answer (score 25):

I solved same problem using css. (Ionıc 3.6)

**Step1**: In `ion-content` add a new class :

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
```

**Step2**: In your CSS add the code below :

```
.no-scroll .scroll-content{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The ion-content has a class called '**scroll-content**'.

With that in mind, go to your **app.css**, inside the **src/app** and add:

---

**app.css**:

```
.scroll-content{overflow-y: hidden;}
```

---

That should leave your ion-content with no scroll, but I'd rather user:

**app.css**:

```
.scroll-content{overflow-y: auto;}
```

since this allows the scroll-content only if the page content overflows the ion-content.

Answer (score 6):

This works in ionic 5:

```
ion-content {
   --overflow: hidden;
}

<ion-content scroll-y="false">
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me on Ionic 5. None of the other answers worked.

Answer (score 3):

For disable scroll in ion-content can use setScrollDisabled() method. You should follow steps below.

In hello.ts

```
 import { app } from 'ionic-angular';

   public class HelloPage
   {
       constructor(private app: App) {};

        ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.app.setScrollDisabled(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
But what if I want one page no scroll instead of whole app no scroll?

Comment: @ReoLim reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952538/how-can-i-disable-or-hide-the-scrollbar-within-an-ionic-2-ion-content .:))

Comment: For newer version of ionic2 it's  this.app._setDisableScroll(true);

Comment: Please make @FrankGoortani's comment included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the scroll you may also don't need the ion-content itself, in my status for example I want to use the ion-grid directly.

```
<!-- my-page.ts >
<ion-header>.......</ion-header>
<ion-grid class="has-header fixed-content">

</ion-grid>
```

and I added some scss for the has-header class:

```
ion-app {
    &.md {
        .has-header {
            margin-top: $toolbar-md-height;
        }
    }
    &.wp {
        .has-header {
            margin-top: $toolbar-wp-height;
        }
    }
    &.ios {
        .has-header {
            margin-top: $toolbar-ios-height;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Content is placed in the scrollable area if provided without a slot. To show a fixed content add `slot="fixed"`.

```
<ion-content>
<div slot="fixed">

</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Using this for displaying non-scrollable skeleton-text while waiting for data to load from database.

Answer (score 0):

As iflagri posted in this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7644) and @shaneparsons pointed in the comments, using

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div ion-fixed>

    Your content here...

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Solve the problem.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to disable the content scrolling you can use**

```
<ion-content [scrollY]="false" >
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content

```
<ion-content [attr.noScroll]="shouldScroll"></ion-content>
    
// scss file:

[noScroll] {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Surprisingly, `no-bounce` attribute did work on my previous project and is not working on a new project that I am currently working on.

I tried @rodrigo-chave's solution with `ion-fixed`. It solved the scrolling problem, but made my content small (as if was zoomed out). Adding 100% CSS width and height properties fixed it.

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
  <div ion-fixed style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    ...
  </div>
</ion-content>
```