# How do I get rid of the white space on the top of my mobile app (Ionic)?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm coding a mobile app page using Ionic, and am running into a problem that I can't really seem to get past.

My problem is that there is always a white strip above my actual page with the time, battery, etc. on the iPhone. It sucks because when I touch the screen and move it up and down, the page will scroll to show that white space behind it.

[image]

My html looks like so:

```
  <ion-content class="slides-scss">

  <ion-slides pager>
   <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button color="primary" [navPush]=closeSlides>Skip</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-footer>
    <ion-row>
          <button ion-button [(navPush)] = "signUp">Sign Up</button>
          <button ion-button [(navPush)] = "login">Login</button>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-footer>

  <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
  <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
  <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>

 </ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
  <ion-toolbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <!-- <img src="assets/img/ica-slidebox-img-4.png" class="slide-image"/> -->
  <h2 class="slide-title">Sign Up Today!</h2>
  <button ion-button large clear icon-end color="primary" [navPush]=signUp>
    Sign Up
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

My typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'slides.html'
})
export class SlidesPage {

constructor (public navCtrl: NavController) {}

slides = [
    {
        title: "Welcome to Village!",
        description: "Meet ...kljsfdlfj.",
        image: "https://data.whicdn.com/images/219181569/large.jpg"
    },
    {
        title: "Connect & Build Community",
        description: "So you never feel alone.",
        image: "assets/imgs/singapore.jpg"
    }
];

closeSlides = LoginPage;
signUp = SignupPage;
login = LoginPage;

}
```

Finally, scss:

```
.slides-scss {
 .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
   background: black;
 }

 .toolbar-background {
   background: linen;
   border-color: transparent;
 }

 .slide-zoom {
   height: 100%;
 }

 .slide-title {
   margin-top: 8.8rem;
   padding:  10px;
 }

  h2 {
   position: relative; 
  }

  p {
   padding: 0 40px;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.5;
   color: #60646B;
   position: relative;

 b {
   color: #000000;
 }
}

ion-slide {
  background-color: linen;
 }

.slide-image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 0;

 position: absolute;
}
}
```

Ideally, the image would stretch all the way to the strip of white space. 
Like how in this picture, the color extends over the white space.
[image]

I really don't know what I'm doing, please help a newbie coder ahhhh!!

Answer (score 1):

- Try getting rid of  `<ion-toolbar>`, and perhaps use a button in the bottom to skip
- Try changing the color of the status bar to a color close to the background color of the page you are showing
- Try disabling scroll by setting `<ion-content no-bounce></ion-content>` or other methods [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414795/ionic-2-ion-content-disable-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the status bar as described here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

constructor( platform : Platform,
             statusBar : StatusBar
             /* other service injections */ ) {

        platform.ready().then( () => {
             statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString( '#553399' );
        }
}
```