# Disable native scroll in Ionic 1.3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, scroll, scrollbar

I'm developing an app with Ionic 1.3.3, and I want it to be available on desktop browsers as well. For this reason, I need to disable the automatic Ionic scroll because it is adapted for touchscreens and not intuitive for computers (maintain click + sliding). I know how to add a browser scrollbar by using overflow:auto; on all my ion-content.

So far I have only managed to hide the Ionic scrollbar, using the following solutions:

```
scrollbar-y="false"
```

on the ion-content, or

```
display: none;
```

on the scrollbar css. However, hiding it is not enough for what I want.

I tried several Ionic 2 solutions (for example [How can I disable or hide the scrollbar within an Ionic 2 <ion-content>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952538/how-can-i-disable-or-hide-the-scrollbar-within-an-ionic-2-ion-content/40826366#40826366)), but they don't seem to work, and they don't all apply since the files are not all the same.

I also tried

```
overflow-scroll="false"
```

on my ion-content, no success.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in one of my codes, I don't now if this could helps you but it works for me:

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
```

You can found some info about this attribute in http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/

Comment: Well well, it was as simple as that. It does exactly what I want, I'm surprised I didn't find it earlier after all the research I made. Thank you sir !

Comment: Yes... I had the same problem some time ago, you're welcome! ^^