# Ionic thinks page has content so adds scroll

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

For some reason Ionic think that my page has content and is adding in a scrollbar. Here is my page:

[image]

And the code for the page:

```
   <ion-header>
       <ion-navbar>
           <ion-title>Week</ion-title>
           <ion-buttons end>
               <button ion-button icon-only (click)="createPage()">
              <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
              </button>
          </ion-buttons>
      </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952538/how-can-i-disable-or-hide-the-scrollbar-within-an-ionic-2-ion-content) thread here which tells you how to remove the scroll bar, which I can do but I want to track down what is causing it to appear in the first place.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can see you are using --lab, if you use ionic serve instead and use chrome dev tool, this scroll bar will be gone. This only happens if you view the app pages with browser engine. If you view this page with mobile, the scroll bar will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looks like the scroll bar has disappeared, but I am still able to scroll a little bit. I'd like to find the cause of this if possible.

Comment: From what I have tried , if you add content into your content section the scroll bar the page will no longer be scroll-able unless you have exceeded the view maximum height. Without digging into the codes, I can safely assume the ```fixed-conten``` has the default property of 100% view height if nothing is in it. Anyway help you find our the answer you want.