# Customize the sidemenu Scrollbar in ionic 3?

Tags: css, scrollbar, ionic3

I am trying to customize the default scrollbar that appears in the Side Menu, along with the scrollbar in the page itself but am unable to do so. I have already referred to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952538/how-can-i-disable-or-hide-the-scrollbar-within-an-ionic-2-ion-content) but it does not seems to be of much use for the page and have got no clues about customizing the scrollbar in the side menu as additionally i need to reduce the space between the elements in sidemenu.

I also tried to hide the scrollbar with the following code but was of no use.

```
     .no-scroll .scroll-content{
     overflow: hidden;
     }
```

Comment: I was able to hide it by adding the following style rules in the `app.scss` file: `div::-webkit-scrollbar { border:none; width:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
div::-webkit-scrollbar-track { border:none; width:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border:none; width:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); }`

Comment: does this works for the sidemenu too ?

Comment: It should work for both

Comment: worked for none in my case

Comment: Could you please create a plunker with your code? That way it'd be easier to see why it doesn't work on your end

Comment: not aware of plunker but would give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following styles in app.scss

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:0px;
}
```

It will reduce the size of the scrollbar to zero.