# Ionic 3 Hide Scrollbar in IOS device

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3

I have tried many thing to hide the scrollbar in IOS devices but it's keep re-appearing.

```
   ::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

I come across this solution a lot but it's not solving my problem. Let me know if someone already fixed this.

Comment: please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952538/how-can-i-disable-or-hide-the-scrollbar-within-an-ionic-2-ion-content

Answer (score 1):

Override the scroll-content, style

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;                                          
}
```

and if you are trying to disable ion-list scroll you should try this

```
div.scroll-content {
    bottom: 0px !important;                                                   
}
```

Comment: Hidden also stops the Scrolling. Bottom: 0px; didn't work. I want to scroll but it shouldn't appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following in your `app.scss` file

```
.scroll-content{
    overflow-y:hidden; // if you are trying to hide the vertical scroll
    //overflow:hidden ; will hide both horizontal and vertical scroll
}
```

### Edit 1

`scrollbar-y="false" on the <ion-content>`
Let me know your outcome

Comment: Hidden also stops the Scrolling. I want to scroll but it shouldn't appear on the screen. In android works so smooth without having to write any css.

Comment: So you want the scroll and don't want to show the thick scroll bar right?

Comment: Yes, in android that scroll is not visible but in ios it appear when scrolling.